Limit network bandwidth
TL;DR: I'm looking to rate-limit network activity:

Linux
Both Mb/s or packets/s can work for me (perfer if both are possible)
Limiting either per interface, per IP or per process can work (prefer if all are possible)
Limit bandwidth without loosing packets
Strongly prefer "standard" solutions (built into the kernel, systemd, or widely distributed user-space tools)


I have two linux servers that talk to each other a lot, and the host provider is sometimes flagging this traffic as DDOS and blocking us for a few hours. I want to implement software rate-limit to solve this. It could be done either at the network adapter level, or at the process execution/encapsulation level.
I've looked at systemd and ulimit but it doesn't seem to offer network bandwidth limiting. I've seen one can change the network adapter rate, but it's too coarse: 10/100/1000 Mbps, unless there is a way to configure arbitrary values ?
I've look into iptables, but from the examples I've seen we can only drop the excess traffic, not delay it, which may have side effects if the upper layers don't implement retry, etc.
And I've seen a lot of more or less exotic tools, which seem to work, but I'm looking for something standard and well-maintained, to avoid security and other long-term issues.

Change to a sane host?

Haha yes but it will take time, I'm looking for a quick fix

Can we assume the hosts are not communicating unnecessarily? Have you considered configuring a tunnel between the different hosts?

@music2myear I had a wireguard tunel, which I just replaced with iptable rules, because apparently the ddos protection is more sensitive to UDP traffic. And no the traffic is not useless, apps need to talk to the DB. But there's room for improvement clearly, we could audit and optimize data access from the apps, add compression, etc. That's doesn't happen overnight.
